# Wordpress User Role to access backend is not working

Tags: wordpress, roles, wordpress-capabilities

I added a user role to access to backend. Even after I added more than 70 capabilities, Wp-admin page is showing "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

```
add_role( 'employer', 'Employer', 
    array(
"switch_themes",
"edit_themes",
"activate_plugins",
"edit_plugins",
"edit_users",
"edit_files",
"manage_options",
"moderate_comments",
"manage_categories",
"manage_links",
"upload_files",
"import",
"unfiltered_html",
"edit_posts",
 "edit_others_posts",
"edit_published_posts",
"publish_posts",
"edit_pages",
"read",
"level_10",
...
 "manage_job_listing_terms",
"edit_job_listing_terms",
"delete_job_listing_terms",
 "assign_job_listing_terms",
"administrator",
    )
);
```

But this is not working.

How can I fix to to access dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are adding role but not actually passing what capabilities needs to be true, Correct syntax is :

```
add_role( 
    'custom_role', 'Custom Role Name',
        array(
            'read' => true,
            'level_0' => true
        )
);
```

[Check out in Documentation : Wordpress Roles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/)